# Normal distribution percentile calculation

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I'm working out the following problem and there is a part that I am not understanding clearly.

- The weight distribution of parcels sent is normal with mean value $12$ lbs and standard deviation 3.5lbs.
- The service wishes to establish a weight value c beyond which there will be a surcharge.
- What value $c$ is such that $99\%$ of all parcels that are at least 1 lb under the surcharge weight?

I feel like I get the general task presented, however there is one part that I am stuck on.
$$
P(x < c-1) = 0.99
$$
$$P\left(z \le \frac {c-1-12}{3.5} \right) = 0.99 $$

$$\frac {c-13}{3.5} = 0.99 $$

I know I have to solve for $c$ but I'm not sure why the answer that I get is wrong from the book's at this point. The book's answer to this question is 21.155 and I'm getting 16.465.

Comment: Intuitive answer: 97.8% (less than 99%) of the parcels will be less than 2 deviations above the mean. 2 deviations above the mean is 19 pounds, so 16.465 can't possibly be right (even excluding the extra pound). Incidentally, this model isn't very good because it states that some packages will weigh less than 0 pounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need $\Phi\left(\dfrac{c-13}{3.5}\right) = 0.99$, not $\dfrac{c-13}{3.5} = 0.99$.

Hence $\dfrac{c-13}{3.5} = \Phi^{-1}(0.99)$, and so $\dfrac{c-13}{3.5} \approx 2.33$.

$\Phi$ is the function tabulated in the back of every book.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Φ? I've never heard about it up until now and thought this was just a normal z-score.

Comment: $\Phi$ is the cumulative probability distribution function of the standard normal distribution.  As I said, the function tabulated in the back of every book.  Thus: $\Phi(1.96) \approx 0.975$, $\Phi(2.33) \approx 0.99$, etc.  So you have $(c-13)/3.5 \approx 2.33$. ${}\qquad{}$